# Using Ternary condition inside a class in Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

How can I write a ternary condition to change the color of this progress-bar when the percentage reaches 57

This is how the code for the progress-bar is set

```
<div
   class="progress-bar"
    role="progressbar"
    :style="{width:(quoteCount / maxQuotes) * 100 + '%'}"
    aria-valuenow="25"
    aria-valuemin="0"
    aria-valuemax="100">
   {{quoteCount}} / {{maxQuotes}}
 </div>
```

..................

So, I want to add the class `progress-bar bg-danger` when I get to 75%

Answer (score 7):

You would need to access the value of the progress bar, so ideally you would `v-model` to some data value, like `progress`. Then just:

`:class="progress > 75 ? 'bg-danger' : '' "`

Comment: This, but maybe use a computed property for your `quoteCount / maxQuotes`.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to OP's question, but I was looking for the same question and it was helpful to get going in the right direction. Hopefully this will help someone else as well...

I wanted to expand/collapse a "group" of navigation items. For example, the following pages *could* live under an "About Us" section of a website.

- Leadership
- History
- Careers

In this example, if any one of those sub-menu items are selected, I want to expand the entire "About Us" navigation group by setting the parent class to `active`. If the user has clicked into a different "group" I want to set the parent class to `collapsed`.

```
<div class="nav item">
    <a class="nav-link"
        :class="(currentGroup === 'about') ? 'active' : 'collapsed'">About Us</a>
    ...
</div>

<div class="subnav-items">
    <a :href="'/leaderhip'"
        :class="{'active':(pathname === 'leadership')}">Leadership</a>
    <a :href="'/history'"
        :class="{'active':(pathname === 'history')}">History</a>
    <a :href="'/careers'"
        :class="{'active':(pathname === 'careers')}">Careers</a>
</div>

...

data: () => ({
    currentGroup: '',
    groups: {
        about: [
            'leadership',
            'history',
            'careers',
        ],
    },
    pathname: '',
}),
created() {
    this.pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

    if (this.groups.about.includes(this.pathname)) {
        this.currentGroup = 'about';
    }
}
```